# Grabbing data from columns with same name in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I currently have 2 dataframes

```
df1=data.frame(q1 = c(1:3),
               q2 = c("One" , "Two" , "Three") , 
               q3 = c(100,231,523),
               q4 = c("red", "green", "blue"),
               q1.2 = c(20:22),
               q2.2 = c("Six" , "Ten" , "Twenty") , 
               q3.2 = c(5,900,121),
               q4.2 = c("purple", "yellow", "white"))
df2=data.frame(x1 = c("q1" , "q2.1" , "q3.2" , "q4.2") ,
               x2 = c("q2" , "q3" , "q3.3" , "q4.4") ,
               x3 = c("q3" , "q2.4" , "q3.3" , "q4.6"), 
               x4 = c("q4" , "q3.6" , "q3.3" , "q4.2"))
```

I need to create 4 different tables. The headers of these tables are each of the rows included in df2 while the observations have to be obtained from df1. As you noticed, some of the headers included in df2 do not exist in df1. I want my 4 tables to include all 4 headers (whether they exist or not) and if it doesnt, the its data should be blank.

I am currently using this code

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
  colnames(df2)<- df2[i,]
  tabla_temp = df1[intersect(names(df1), names(df2))]
  tname <- paste0("tabla_", i)
  assign(tname, tabla_temp)
  rm(tabla_temp)
}
```

I get my loop working but i get tables with different amounts of columns (only those which exist in df1).

Any idea how i can get my loop to create same size tables with non existing headers to have blank obs instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
lapply(df2, function(x) {
  merge(
    df1[names(df1) %in% levels(x)],
    read.table(text = "", col.names = levels(x)), all = T)
})

$x1
  q1 q3.2   q4.2 q2.1
1  1    5 purple   NA
2  2  900 yellow   NA
3  3  121  white   NA

$x2
     q2  q3 q3.3 q4.4
1   One 100   NA   NA
2 Three 523   NA   NA
3   Two 231   NA   NA

$x3
   q3 q2.4 q3.3 q4.6
1 100   NA   NA   NA
2 231   NA   NA   NA
3 523   NA   NA   NA

$x4
     q4   q4.2 q3.3 q3.6
1  blue  white   NA   NA
2 green yellow   NA   NA
3   red purple   NA   NA
```

**data**

```
df1=data.frame(q1 = c(1:3),
               q2 = c("One" , "Two" , "Three") , 
               q3 = c(100,231,523),
               q4 = c("red", "green", "blue"),
               q1.2 = c(20:22),
               q2.2 = c("Six" , "Ten" , "Twenty") , 
               q3.2 = c(5,900,121),
               q4.2 = c("purple", "yellow", "white"))

df2=data.frame(x1 = c("q1" , "q2.1" , "q3.2" , "q4.2") ,
               x2 = c("q2" , "q3" , "q3.3" , "q4.4") ,
               x3 = c("q3" , "q2.4" , "q3.3" , "q4.6"), 
               x4 = c("q4" , "q3.6" , "q3.3" , "q4.2"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there any way i can keep the columns in the same order they are in df2?
For instance, the first table you show me has (q1 q3.2   q4.2 q2.1) but i would need it to be (q1 q2.1   q3.2 q4.2).

My end goal is to combine all the tables so i must have the columns in the predefined order so that the data is not mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [any_of()](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/all_of.html) function from dplyr. It selects the variables which match the names and ignores those which do not. I will use a list to store matrices from the loop. They can be accessed using `df_modified[[i]]`.

```
# Loading libraries
library(tidyverse)

df_modified = list()
for(i in 1:nrow(df2))
{
   vars = as.character(df2[i,])
   df_modified[[i]] = df1 %>% 
      select(any_of(vars))
}
```

Output

```
> df_modified
[[1]]
  q1    q2  q3    q4
1  1   One 100   red
2  2   Two 231 green
3  3 Three 523  blue

[[2]]
   q3
1 100
2 231
3 523

[[3]]
  q3.2
1    5
2  900
3  121

[[4]]
    q4.2
1 purple
2 yellow
3  white
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although it does not quite get me what i need.

I need the 4 tables you show me to all have 4 columns and respect the order in df2. If the title name (for example q4.2) is included in df1, then table 4 should have 4 columns. The first being q4 with data, the following 2 q3.6 and q3.3 being empty, and the last q4.2 with data.

Is that clearer as to what i am looking for?

Comment: What do you mean by title name? What's the title name in `q4.2`? And how are you deciding which (empty) columns should be included in the data frame as well?

Comment: By title name i meant column name, my bad. Each row in df2 contains the 4 column headers i want in my table. The data observations for the table are obtained from df1. If the column header in the table exists as a column header in df1, then i want to grab the data, if it does not, then i want the column to have blank observations.